# php/html show text with spaces in form

Tags: php, html

I have the following code inside php. The problem is in the input address show only the first word. I think something going on with concatenation but I don't know how to solve it.

```
$Name="John;
$Surname="Borg";
$Address="Leoforos Lemesou, 74";
echo '
  <form method="post">
            <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value=' . $Name . ' /><br>
            <label for="surname">Surname:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" value=' . $Surname . ' /><br>
            <label for="address">Address</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="address" name="address" value=' . $Address . ' /><br>

            <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit">
        </form>
    ';
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add the quotation marks around value for address. You should actually add it for all the text fields!